# Ubuntu 22.04 can't recognize and charge BAT0 of Lenovo Thinkpad T460s

Tags: 22.04, power-management, battery, thinkpad

Recently I ordered battery replacements for my Lenovo Thinkpad T460s which runs Ubuntu 22.04. While installing the batteries, Ubuntu had no issues recognizing the extra battery but didn't seem to recognize/charge the main one. "Power statistics" shows the following:
[image]

Also tried to run `sudo tlp-stat -s -c -b`:

```
--- TLP 1.5.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings:
defaults.conf L0004: TLP_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0005: TLP_WARN_LEVEL="3"
defaults.conf L0006: TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT="0"
defaults.conf L0007: DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0008: DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT="2"
defaults.conf L0009: MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC="15"
defaults.conf L0010: MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT="60"
defaults.conf L0011: CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC="balance_performance"
defaults.conf L0012: CPU_ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT="balance_power"
defaults.conf L0013: SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0014: SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT="1"
defaults.conf L0015: NMI_WATCHDOG="0"
defaults.conf L0016: DISK_DEVICES="nvme0n1 sda"
defaults.conf L0017: DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
defaults.conf L0018: DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
defaults.conf L0019: DISK_APM_CLASS_DENYLIST="usb ieee1394"
defaults.conf L0020: DISK_IOSCHED="keep keep"
defaults.conf L0021: SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC="med_power_with_dipm max_performance"
defaults.conf L0022: SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT="med_power_with_dipm min_power"
defaults.conf L0023: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC="on"
defaults.conf L0024: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0025: AHCI_RUNTIME_PM_TIMEOUT="15"
defaults.conf L0026: PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC="default"
defaults.conf L0027: PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT="default"
defaults.conf L0028: RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC="auto"
defaults.conf L0029: RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0030: RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC="default"
defaults.conf L0031: RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT="default"
defaults.conf L0032: WIFI_PWR_ON_AC="off"
defaults.conf L0033: WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT="on"
defaults.conf L0034: WOL_DISABLE="Y"
defaults.conf L0035: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC="1"
defaults.conf L0036: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT="1"
defaults.conf L0037: SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER="Y"
defaults.conf L0038: BAY_POWEROFF_ON_AC="0"
defaults.conf L0039: BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT="0"
defaults.conf L0040: BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
defaults.conf L0041: RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC="on"
defaults.conf L0042: RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT="auto"
defaults.conf L0043: RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_DENYLIST="mei_me nouveau radeon"
defaults.conf L0044: USB_AUTOSUSPEND="1"
defaults.conf L0045: USB_EXCLUDE_AUDIO="1"
defaults.conf L0046: USB_EXCLUDE_BTUSB="0"
defaults.conf L0047: USB_EXCLUDE_PHONE="0"
defaults.conf L0048: USB_EXCLUDE_PRINTER="1"
defaults.conf L0049: USB_EXCLUDE_WWAN="0"
defaults.conf L0050: USB_AUTOSUSPEND_DISABLE_ON_SHUTDOWN="0"
defaults.conf L0051: RESTORE_DEVICE_STATE_ON_STARTUP="0"
defaults.conf L0052: RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT="0"
defaults.conf L0053: NATACPI_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0054: TPACPI_ENABLE="1"
defaults.conf L0055: TPSMAPI_ENABLE="1"

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad T460s 20F9003GUS
BIOS           = N1CET78W (1.46 )
OS Release     = Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel         = 5.15.0-56-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 22 19:54:14 UTC 2022 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic root=UUID=a8dc07c9-10ea-48ea-894d-20b610fe44b6 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Init system    = systemd v249 (249.11-0ubuntu3.6)
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
RDW state      = enabled
Last run       = 19:56:34,     49 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: thinkpad
Supported features: charge thresholds, recalibration
Driver usage:
* natacpi (thinkpad_acpi) = active (charge thresholds)
* tpacpi-bat (acpi_call)  = active (recalibration)
Parameter value ranges:
* START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:  0(off)..96(default)..99
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0/1:   1..100(default)

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = (not available)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = (not available)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =      0 (or not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Not charging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_start_threshold =     99 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold   =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT1 (Ultrabay / Slice / Replaceable)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = SMP
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = 01AV406
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    =      0 (or not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design             =  24000 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full                    =  22360 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now                     =  22340 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Not charging

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_start_threshold =      0 [%]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/charge_control_end_threshold   =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT1.forceDischarge                              =      0

Charge                                                      =   99.9 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   93.2 [%]

+++ Charge total                                            =   99.9 [%]
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: What firmware version are you running? Is it current? Does the battery charge under other OSes, e.g. under Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue has resolved on its own. I'm not sure how, but it seems when the second battery got discharged and my laptop turned off, it somehow reset the power management tool and now after I charged it, Ubuntu recognizes both of them:[image]